# Install Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.6 in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am having windows 8.1 laptop and installed VirtualBox 4.3.26. I am trying to install OEL 6.6 that I downloaded from Oracle site.

I have 5 iso images

```
Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 source DVD 2--->V52217-01
Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 for x86_64 (64 Bit)--->V52218-01
Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 UEK Boot ISO image for x86_64 (64 bit)--->V52220-01
Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 Boot iso image for x86_64 (64 bit)--->V52219-01
Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 source DVD 1--->V52216-01
```

I have setup the VM and tried to start the VM to install Linux. I selected the "Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 Boot iso image for x86_64 (64 bit)--->V52219-01" as IDE Primary Master as this will be the boot disk. It goes to the installation screen, but then it asks for the source files, not sure how to proceed, I tried to change the image to "Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 source DVD 1--->V52216-01" but it does not help.

[image: selected option]

[image: this is where I get stuck]

I tried to update/ create new hard drive, but it did not help. I tried using another image that I downloaded from the net(it was a single file) and it worked fine.

Any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISO image you need to map as virtual DVD in the VBox Virtual Machine settings is the 3.7 GB one:

> Oracle Linux Release 6 Update 6 for x86_64 (64 Bit) `V52218-01.iso`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to map it and get the install started.